# Should questions related to results from 23andMe and other Gene services be On-Topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

In the past week or two I have seen a two posts asking questions related to information obtained from 23andMe or similar services.

I previously expressed that I thought it was not a good idea to answer these questions, as without a knowledge of the total genetic profile of the person, their family history, and the perspective of a genetics counselor, there was a risk that information provided could be unknowingly harmful.

#### Related Questions

- [Understanding different genetic terminology - Genotype vs SNP](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41591/understanding-different-genetic-terminology-genotype-vs-snp)
- [What does it mean to have a Y-DNA Haplogroup "R-M512"?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41229/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-y-dna-haplogroup-r-m512)

Should questions related to results from genetics testing services be On-Topic or Off-Topic for Biology SE?

Answer (score 2):

Questions about DNA testing from genetic genealogy services (23andMe, FamilyTreeDNA, etc.) are on-topic at [Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com).

Particularly the second question ([What does it mean to have a Y-DNA Haplogroup "R-M512"?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41229/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-y-dna-haplogroup-r-m512)) would be better asked on Genealogy & Family History SE.

Answer (score 0):

These are certainly bioinformatics questions which would be deemed within the scope of Biology.SE unless you want those questions to migrate to https://www.biostars.org